# Magento2 error - The file "/home/hmsdgwtu/public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/" doesn't exist or not a file

Tags: magento2

I have created another store in one website in magento2. After that , when I am editing product I am getting this error

> The file "/home/hmsdgwtu/public_html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/"
>   doesn't exist or not a file

I am stuck on that anyone have any idea about how to fix that error ?

Comment: Have you find a fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems you don't have permission to pub/media folder

check below link for permission

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Or just give full permission to pub/media folder

```
chmod -R 777 pub/media
```

To set full project permission like

```
 find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && chmod 777 ./app/etc && chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Comment: Hello Hitesh,

Thanks for replying. after giving permission still I am getting the same error. would you please suggest any other solution for this ?

Thanks,
Ritika

Comment: Are you using windows ?